# How to start a secondary rsync task if and only if a primary rsync task completes successfully?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rsync

#### Background

I have two servers, `ServerSource` and `ServerDestination` (running Ubuntu 18.04), connected over the internet.

I'm using rsync (running on `ServerDestination`) to make a (public) mirror on `ServerDestination` of a specific primary (private/internal) source directory on `ServerSource`.

#### Problem

My problem is that, given the sometimes unpredictable nature of Internet connections, sometimes `ServerDestination` cannot contact `ServerSource`.  Because my rsync task will delete files on `ServerDestination` that do not exist on `ServerSource`, when the rsync task finds no files (because it cannot connect) it will delete the entire (public) mirrored directory on `ServerDestination`.

This means that the public mirror is empty and useless until the next scheduled rsync task is run. It also means that the *entire* source directory has to be re-copied and re-transferred again starting from zilch, which is a waste of time and bandwidth.

#### Objective

It seems to me that I could solve this situation by splitting the process into two transfers:

1. `rsync-process-1` copies the directory from `ServerSource` to `ServerDestination` exactly as I am doing now, except that instead of copying to the final publicly-accessible directory, it copies to a temporary "cache" directory on `ServerDestination`.
2. If and only if `rsync-process-1` completes successfully, I will run `rsync-process-2` which simply copies the files from the temporary directory on `ServerDestination` to the final publicly-accessible directory within the same machine.

Using this method, if for any reason the `rsync-process-1` fails, then `rsync-process-2` will never run, and the older version of the publicly-accessible directory will remain untouched and still mostly useful until the next successful `rsync-process-1` completes.

#### Questions

1. Is my proposed solution the best way to accomplish this task, or is there a more elegant method, perhaps built into rsync?
2. If this two-stage rsync solution is the best way, what would be the easiest way to script it?  I [found this list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737204/comprehensive-list-of-rsync-error-codes) of rsync exit/error codes, but in that same thread some commenters seem to indicate that rsync doesn't always reliably output error codes to the shell.

Comment: Easy to solve: Make the direction of the Rsync from “ServerSource” to “ServerDestination” and do not have “ServerDestination” do any of the heavy lifting. And also change your Rsync command to not delete/remove the files on the destination. Simple and solved that way. Source is in control and if you don’t remove/delete files then there will always be files on the destination.

Comment: Unfortunately setting up rsync on the source is not an option as it is a proprietary machine that is not running (a standard) linux and for which I do not have admin control.  Also, I need rsync to delete/remove files on the destination because the source serves as the "master" for the public mirror.  If a file is removed from the source, I *want* it to be removed from the destination.  That behavior is functioning as intended.